# How to hide scroll bar without using overflow "hidden"?

Tags: html, css

image1

[image]

in this image, there is no scroll bar but if I scroll down inside diagram component div element scrollbar will occur

image2 with scrollbar

[image]

how can I hide that scrollbar without setting `overflow: hidden`

**references**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure the wrapping element is fitting the content and there won't be a scrollbar. Perhaps it has a fixed height or it could be some other css, we don't know from an image.

Comment: Make it transparrent.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200639/transparent-scrollbar-with-css

Comment: @DominicTobias, see question again I added new images

Answer (score 3):

Just use the CSS of it like that:

```
selector-with-overflow::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

notice doesnt work on all browsers but should work on the most common ones

Comment: I don't want to set overflow "hidden".that is majar part of my question

Comment: @VijayVJ where did you see `overflow:hidden` in his code?

Comment: visibility: hidden

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd ever want to hide the indication that a page is overflowing, see this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nT38/868/ for the `css` for a scrollbar that isn't visible yet still scrollable.  Here's the breakdown:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I checked that Jsfiddle, if change widh and height, scroll is not displayed. I think there is some pblm

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted?  To **not** display the scrollbar?

Comment: check this link please..   http://npmci.syncfusion.com/production/javascript/demos/#/material/diagram/default-functionalities.html

Comment: You shouldn't have different layouts and functionalities - if you are going to hide the scrollbar you should do so across the board.  The example you provided does not cater for scrolling via other means than a scrollbar so it would be a terrible user experience to remove the scrollbar from that example.