# How can I make the scrollbar transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is that the scroll is overlaid and transparent, so the elements behind it are shown through.

[image]

And This is what I want the scrollbar to look like.

[image]

[Transparent scrollbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200639/transparent-scrollbar-with-css)

I tried all of the code in the above question, but it failed.

My current css is this.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 10px;
background: transparent url('../../assets/transparentPNG.png') repeat !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: transparent url('../../assets/transparentPNG.png') repeat !important;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
    background: transparent url('../../assets/transparentPNG.png') repeat !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
    background: transparent url('../../assets/transparentPNG.png') repeat !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: rgba(67, 62, 78, 0.1);
opacity: 0.1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent scrollbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200639/transparent-scrollbar-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide the scrollbar, here's an easy fix:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
  ...Lots of text
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 }
div {
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what I wanted to do is not remove the scrollbars, but transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this it works for me .

```css
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
```